# Changing POP settings in Google Apps Gmail

Tags: gmail

I have an email address, name@mydomain.com which I have integrated with the Google Apps Gmail. I recently changed the servers which host this email address and I'd like to integrate it with Gmail again. To do this I believe I have to edit the POP settings in Gmail under the Accounts menu.

The problem is there is only an option to add a new account, not to edit an existing one. Trying to add my current email, name@mydomain.com gives me an error. Does anyone know of a way I can edit this so I keep my existing email address and not have to make a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to add MX records on your email address, name@mydomain.com, and point them to Google Apps MX. I use GoDaddy, but your web host provider should have similar instructions.
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33353

I hope this helps!